# Using ExecuteNonQuery to run a Stored Procedure isn't creating my table, but the table is created when executing the sp in SSMS

Tags: c#, t-sql, dynamic-sql, executenonquery

Some notes:

1. `ExecuteNonQuery` returns -1
2. `ExecuteNonQuery` will drop the table (`@droptable`), but it will not create the new table (`@code`)
3. the length of the `@code` query is 10265 characters
4. The stored procedure runs perfectly fine in SSMS and returns 22 rows in the table

Are there any ideas as to why C#'s `ExecuteNonQuery` function doesn't seem to be executing the 'exec(@code)' portion of the stored procedure?

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_create_EditControlResultsPivot] 
as
begin
    declare @t nvarchar (250); 
    set @t = 'editControlResults'

    declare @newtable nvarchar(250); 
    set @newtable = 'dbo.' + @t + 'Pivot'

    declare @nonPivotColumn1 nvarchar(250); 
    set @nonPivotColumn1 = 'num'

    declare @nonPivotColumn2 nvarchar(25); 
    set @nonPivotColumn2 = 'File_Name'

    declare @droptable nvarchar(max); 
    set @droptable =  
'if EXISTS (select * from sys.objects where object_id = object_id(N''' + @newtable + '''))
begin drop table ' + @newtable + ' end
'

    declare @i int 
    set @i = 1;

    declare @itemList nvarchar(max);
    declare @code nvarchar(max);

    while @i <= (
        select COUNT(*) 
        from sys.columns c 
        left join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id 
        where 1=1 
          and c.name not like @nonPivotColumn1 
          and c.name not like @nonPivotColumn2
          and t.name = @t
    ) 
    begin

    set @itemList = @itemList + ', ' +
    (
        select col from 
        (
            select c.name as col, ROW_NUMBER () over (order by c.name) as num from
            sys.columns c left join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id 
            where 1=1
            and c.name not like @nonPivotColumn1
            and c.name not like @nonPivotColumn2
            and t.name = @t 
        ) sub where num = @i
    )
    set @i = @i + 1
  end

  set @itemList = (select substring(@itemList, 2, LEN(@itemList)))

  set @code = '
  SELECT ' + @nonpivotcolumn2 + ', Item
  into ' + @newtable + '
FROM
(SELECT ' + @nonpivotcolumn2 + ', ' + @itemList + '
FROM ' + @t + ') sub
UNPIVOT
(Value FOR Item IN (' + @itemList + ')
) AS sub
where Value = ''true''
'

exec(@droptable)
exec(@code);
--print(len(@code))
END
--exec sp_create_EditControlResultsPivot
```

Comment: Where is the relevant C# code?

Comment: "NonQuery" means "not a Query", which  means, "not a SELECT"

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: No prefix is better. At least, no prefix that means "stored procedure". You'll know it's a stored procedure because of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` at the start of it. You won't need a prefix to tell you that.

Comment: Very much appreciated. In case it is unclear, the @code query is a "select into"

Comment: @BrianHartigan How do you know that the `@droptable` query is being executed? Does that mean that you have seen the table there after running in SSMS, then you run via C#, and then doing a `SELECT` on that table in SSMS gives an error that the table no longer exists? If you want to see if the `@code` query has been truncated, why don't you add the following just above the `EXEC(@code)` line: `SELECT @code AS [query] INTO tempdb.dbo.CodeQuery;`. Then run via C#. Then run `SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.CodeQuery;` in SSMS.

Answer (score 2):

The ExecuteNonQuery Method returns the number of rows affected use the ExecuteReader method instead.

[SqlCommand.ExecuteReader Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)

The only way to return data from ExecuteNonQuery would be via an Output parameter.

Comment: @code isn't returning data, rather it executes a "select into" My apologies for not making that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your comment #3. the length of the @code query is 10265 characters...could be an issue...I think the call from C# is chopping it to only 4000 or 8000 chars...

Since you are not expecting a resultset, ExecuteNonQuery is good.

Things to try:

1. Try inserting the content of the @code variable (inside the procedure) in a table and see if you are getting the correct sql...both when executed from SSMS and from C# call
2. If you get a valid sql query in step 1 (which I doubt)...try executing that query in SSMS to see if it really works...

Comment: It looks like he _is_ expecting a resultset. That's what he means when he says "my table is returned when I execute the sp in ssms".

Comment: Much appreciated. The @code query is in fact a "select into," and executing the stored procedure in SSMS creates the 22 row table in the database, as expected.<br> The title of this question is not clear on that.

Comment: @John...he already gave us his query...we can infer from it and don't have to rely on how semantically good his formal statement is...cheers...